# How to check the end of ListBox vertical scroll bar in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, listbox

When you add values ​​to a ListBox in MFC, a vertical scrollbar is automatically created.
At this time, we want to create a function that adds more values ​​when the automatically generated vertical scroll bar reaches the end.
If you know a method or method to determine if the scrollbar has reached the end, please let me know.

If I need to use OnVScroll(), please tell me how to check the end of the vertical scroll bar of the ListBox.

The variable of my ListBox is

```
CListBox m_ListBox Word;
```

Comment: The declaration `CListBox m_ListBox Word;` looks wrong to me.

Comment: This seems wrong to me. What if you do not have enough items to fill one page of scrolling? Suggestion 1: Add aside an "Add entry" button. Suggestion 2: Add a special entry "Add entry" at the end of your listbox, which when selected does what it says.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_ListBox_Word.GetScrollPos(SB_VERT)
```

Using the above source, you can get the pos value of the current scroll bar.

You can refer to MSDN below. Thank you to those who answered my question.